# ERROR: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This morning I was getting this error when executing `docker-compose up`:

```
docker-compose up
```

> ERROR: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem was that one or more image where corrupted.

I had to start running my images one by one with:

`docker-compose up <service 1> <service 2>...`

until I found the broken one, which was the `backoffice` image.

Then I rebuilt that image with:

`docker-compose build --no-cache <broken service>`

and finally everything started working nicely again.

Answer (score 79):

I think the easier way is to remove all cache and containers and pull them again.

```
docker system prune --all
docker volume prune 
docker-compose up
```

I think this will solve the error.

Comment: you may not want to get rid of volumes as they hold data, best to find the corrupted image and re-create it

Comment: Yes if you have data (non-recoverable) then u may try to find corrupted image and container and remove it.

Comment: That works, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

It happened because i restarted my docker in between running my docker image, which had corrupted the image. I restarted my system, and then ran the below command. `--no-cache` is the key:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up
```

You can also find the corrupted the image and use below command for the image:

```
docker build -t karthik3030/apigateway -f  "apigateway/Dockerfile" . --no-cache
```

Reference to docker github that supports this solution:

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396#issuecomment-310337418

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot run with the verbose flag --verbose

```
 docker-compose.exe --verbose -f ./compose.yml up
```

In my case I had to remove specific corrupt images that were only indicated when running up with the verbose flag